# How to remove or personalize a scrollbar in a div without using overflow auto?

Tags: html, css

The issue I'm facing involves the header design of my webpage. It features a horizontal sliding gallery of images representing various brands. However, an unwanted horizontal scrollbar has appeared within the container div for these images. This scrollbar disrupts the overall visual appeal of the page, and I'm seeking a solution to either customize its appearance or remove it entirely while retaining the smooth sliding functionality between the images.
This is the CSS code of the container and the cards.

```
.cards-container {
  display: flex;
  width: auto; 
  height: auto; /* Cambiado de 100% a auto para ajustar la altura automáticamente */
  margin-top: 2cm;
  padding: 0.5cm;
}

.card {
  width: 4.7cm; /* Aumentado el ancho de las tarjetas a 14rem */
  height: 4.7cm; /* Aumentado la altura de las tarjetas a 18rem */
  margin-right: 1.2rem;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-color: transparent;
  transition: transform 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.card:hover {
  transform: translateY(-5px);
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.card img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.card:hover:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

And this is how it looks now:

[image]

I've tried using `overflow-x: auto` and `overflow-y: auto`, but while this resolves the scrollbar issue, it distorts and stretches the images and cards. Therefore, I'm seeking a solution that addresses the scrollbar problem without causing any deformation or distortion to the cards.

Comment: Seems like html codes are necessary to find the reason and providing an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 1):

- You can detect what is the position of scrollbar on x-axis or y-axis by
  `overflow-x: auto`
  or
  `overflow-y: auto`

-And you can customize the style of scrollbar by

```
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}
```

- And for more information's visit this page
  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp